# How to check all the values in IN clause of query exist in column of table or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a requirement where I need to check all the values of `IN` clause exists in one column of SQL Server table or not.

How will I be able to find this?

I was trying something like this.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM workflow_attributes
        WHERE attribute_name IN (
                'Mukund_Test_1'
                ,'Mukund_Test_2'
                ,'Mukund_Test_3'
                )
        )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'not exist'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'exists'
END
```

Comment: Mm try replacing null with 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` (or `COUNT(DISTINCT)`):

```
IF 3 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_name)
        FROM workflow_attributes
        WHERE attribute_name IN ('Mukund_Test_1', 'Mukund_Test_2', 'Mukund_Test_3')
       )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'exists'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'not exists'
END
```

Comment: can you please help me in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44926109/need-where-in-which-work-as-and-for-each-value-with-join-query-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @tbl as table (attribute_name varchar(100))
insert into @tbl values ('Mukund_Test_1'),('Mukund_Test_2'),('Mukund_Test_3') 
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM workflow_attributes w left join @tbl t on w.attribute_name = t.attribute_name
        WHERE t.attribute_name is null
        )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'not exist'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'exists'
END
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.