# Link two tables with Order: MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this table called `user_friends`:

```
accid  |  user1  |  user2
1       mark_12     john_24
2       john_24     jim_01
3       mark_12     jim_01
4       nico_7      mark_12
```

And this table called `users_students`:

```
studentuniqueid  |  firstname  |  lastname  |  age 
mark_12           Mark Anthony   Sierra       20
john_24           Johhny         Powers       21
jim_01            James          Sanders      21
nico_7            Nicolai        Renade       19 
janice_53         Janice         Allaine      24
peter_41          Peter          Allan        21
```

Now, here's what I wanted to do:

1.Select all entry/data in the `user_friends` table that has `mark_12` (Mark's ID). Mark's ID could either be on `user1` or `user2` right? So I can just use `SELECT * FROM user_friends WHERE user1 = 'mark_12' OR user2 = 'mark_12'` and echo its `accid`, it will then display:

`1, 3, 4` since `mark_12` appears on those entries on the table.

2.Now I want to select and link the `user_friends` and `users_student` so that I could alphabetically arrange Mark's friends based on the `user_friends` table ORDERING them based on the `lastname` on the `users_student` table. I know this is possible, I just don't know how to do it yet.

I tried:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT user_friends.accid,users_student.studentuniqueid FROM user_friends INNER JOIN IN (user_friends.user1,user_friends.user2)=users_student.studentuniqueid WHERE user1 = '$user_id' OR user2 = '$user_id' ORDER BY users_student.lastname ASC ";
```

And also:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_friends.accid,users_student.studentuniqueid FROM user_friends INNER JOIN user_friends.user1,user_friends.user2=users_student.studentuniqueid WHERE user1 = '$user_id' OR user2 = '$user_id' ORDER BY users_student.lastname ASC ";
```

But somehow didn't work. 
I want to achieve something like:

```
Mark's Friends:

Johnny Powers
Nicolai Renade
James Sanders
```

Comment: do it like below:- `select * from users_students LEFT JOIN user_friends ON user_friends.user2 = users_students.studentuniqueid where user_friends.user1 ="mark_12" order by users_student.lastname ASC;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like below:-

```
SELECT * FROM users_students LEFT JOIN user_friends ON user_friends.user2 = users_students.studentuniqueid WHERE (user_friends.user1 ="mark_12" OR user_friends.user2 ="mark_12" ) ORDER BY users_student.lastname ASC;
```

Output:- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd4043/6/0

***Now your full code need to look like this (what you asked in comment):-***

```
<?php
    //comment these two lines when your code satrted working fine
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    //i have hard-code below two lines so comment them while using at your end
    $user_uniqueid = "mark_12";

    $con = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','ourdesignz','stack');


    $mf_sql = "SELECT * FROM users_students LEFT JOIN user_friends ON user_friends.user2 = users_students.studentuniqueid WHERE (user_friends.user1 ='$user_uniqueid' OR user_friends.user2 ='$user_uniqueid' ) ORDER BY users_students.lastname ASC ";

    $mf_result = mysqli_query($con,$mf_sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    while($mf_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mf_result)){
        $friend_user1 = $mf_row['User1'];
        $friend_user2 = $mf_row['User2'];


        if($friend_user1!==$user_uniqueid){
          $ind_uniqueid =$friend_user1;
        }

        if($friend_user2!==$user_uniqueid){
          $ind_uniqueid =$friend_user2;
        }

        $us2_sql = "SELECT lastname FROM users_students WHERE studentuniqueid = '$ind_uniqueid' ORDER BY users_students.lastname ASC";
        $us2_result = mysqli_query($con,$us2_sql);
        $us2_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($us2_result);


        $st_lastname = $us2_row['lastname'];

        echo $st_lastname."<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it but it only selects all "mark_12" on the `user2` column. It skips it if "mark_12" is on `user1`'s column. Is there anyway I could make it select both `user1` and `user2`?

Comment: Yes, it's working a bit. There's just some bug I think because P show's up before B,, and A is below B. I'm trying to fix it now

Comment: I figured out the problem, it's on how I display it. Your code was actually working. Please help me out....https://jsfiddle.net/0Lgg3rep/

Comment: did you get it?

Comment: nope doesn't work... cccc and pppp still remains on top... I think it's because when it reads that user1 is not the user's id,, it then displays it,, after that it just moves on to the other data...

Comment: @Dranreb  i have created your tables at my end and created a working snippet.I have added that code in my answer.Use that.(just comment hard-coded value `$user_uniqueid` and `$con` code)

Comment: `ON user_friends.user2` I think that's the problem sir. It only arranges the `user2` table. If I change it to `ON user_friends.user1` , it only arranges `user1` . I tried `ON user_friends.user1,user_friends.user2` it doesn't work... I'm sorry if I take so much of your time, I just really have no one to turn to. Like I code here alone,,,

Comment: @Dranreb  please ask a new question with complete table data +your code effort and what is coming and what you expected. Please don't forget to add complete data of both tables.It's really hard to understand here.Also remove all these comments when you are going to ask a new question.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have solved it and made a demo for you in the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd4043/7)

```
SELECT users_students.FirstName, users_students.LastName FROM users_students 
LEFT JOIN user_friends ON user_friends.user2 = users_students.studentuniqueid 
WHERE (user_friends.user1 ="mark_12" OR user_friends.user2 ="mark_12" ) 
ORDER BY users_students.lastname ASC
```

Now you can change your `mark_12` by your`variable`

Answer (score 1):

you should use inner join on the result for the select for filter the accid

```
  select 
      t.accid
    , users_student.studentuniqueid 
    , users_student.firstname,
    , users_student.lastname  
  from (
  select accid 
  from user_friends
  where user1 = 'mark_12' 
  or user2 = 'mark_12' 
  ) t on. t.accid = users_student.studentuniqueid
  order by users_student.lastname ASC
```

Comment: can you help me to solve this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44926109/remove-single-quotes-from-where-in-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Thanks, I don't get the `t.accid` and the `t on. t.accid` part. What's `t`?

Comment: the from clause based on subselect need  a name for the table gernerated  by select  .. t is the name for this table

Comment: It displays an error : `'on. t.accid = users_student.studentuniqueid ORDER BY users_student.lastname ASC`

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'on. t.accid = users_student.studentuniqueid ORDER BY users_student.lastname ASC`

Comment: answer  updated ... missing point in users_student.studentuniqueid

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
select * from user_students where StudentUniqueId in (select user1 from user_friends where user2='mark_12' union select user2 from user_friends where user1 ='mark_12');
```

Comment: `Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Unknown column 'studentuniqueid' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery`

Comment: @Dranreb now I have updated my query it's select from user_students table